# Chrome render different than Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I've just uploaded a beta version of my website marcotronconi.com that I build up on chrome. I have no idea why, the safari render is messed up.

Any fixing idea?

P.s. It might be a silly question, but I'm new to css and html.
thanks

Comment: Please add the relevant codes. And you may want to check [`Vendor Prefixes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers render a web site the same way. Browser's developpers may implement tools and functionnality to make them more attractive / performant.
The most famous example was Internet Explorer as it was massively deployed but did not implement some W3C rules.

Creating a website compatible on most browsers can be a long and hard path but i suggest you starts by studiing some usefull css reset tools as :

- [eric meyer's reset CSS](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/)
- [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Then when building your layout feel free to check if what you plan to use is accessible by asking caniuse.com website.

Last but not least, codepen.io website can freely help you implement and test your code.

Hope this helps